# Couchdb: Login with "Remember me" function

Tags: session, couchdb

I want to implement login feature with couchdb, and want to add "Remember me" function. For example, if user login with out remember me, session will be destroy after 24h, other hand session will be destroy after 7 days.

But in couch DB, I can not check if user check on "Remember me" or not to modify expire time of session.

Comment: That's because CouchDB is a database, not a web application framework. What are you trying to do? Are you just talking about logging in as a DB user in Futon? Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, I use login of CouchDB in Futon but I must create a function "Remember me". You mean there is no way to do that and I must using an web framework to handler session?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You are talking about "implementing features for users" but Futon is a back-end administrative interface. You're not using Futon as an interface for end users... right?

Comment: Yes, I create my own UI and using API of CouchDB to login and retrive data.

Comment: You shouldn't be logging your users directly into your database. Your DB access should all be through a single system user and your end-user permissions should be managed separately in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cookie-based authentication and send a auth request to the _session endpoint. CouchDB will then return a Cookie.

The token is valid 10minutes by default, but you can configure the lifetime using the timeout setting in the couch_httpd_auth section of your local.ini (use `couchdb -c` to locate it)

More info: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html#cookies

Comment: I can config it to 7 days, but if users don't check on Checkbox Remember me, I just want their session expire for 1 day.